# Adding Webpacker custom loader makes webpacker behave incorrectly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, webpack, ruby-on-rails-5, webpacker

if I add a custom loader, for example the haml loader:

```
// config/webpack/rules/haml.js
module.exports = {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.haml$/,
          loader: 'haml-haml-loader'
        }
      ]
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.haml']
    }
  }



// config/webpack/base.js
const { webpackConfig, merge } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const hamlConfig = require('./rules/haml')

module.exports = merge(hamlConfig, webpackConfig)
```

some application files stop loading. For instance, I got Angular error because corresponding file wasn't loaded:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
```

just removing this custom loader makes everything work fine. When ANY custom loader is added the application files stop loading for some reason. Any thoughts?

Webpacker version is 6. Official documentation: https://github.com/rails/webpacker#typescript